# How Angular Application Run? which file executes first?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

Are main.ts and index.html runs parallelly? if no, which file runs first? if main.ts, then how angular knows that it should display index.html in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone visits your site index.html will be the first file served. Form here the javascript will be loaded which will then bootstrap Angular. The Angular CLI automatically adds the import for your javascript to index.html during the build (`ng build`). Build your application and look in your build directory (dist/ by default) you will find the index.html and inside it there will be some script tags: something like: `<script src="main.123.js"></script>`. This is the compiled version of main.ts and is how main.ts is loaded and executed in your application.

You can see how the angular app is structured here: https://angular.io/guide/file-structure. If you find index.html on this page it explains how this is the entrypoint to your app.

Comment: A simple way to prove this is correct is by navigating to your website with your browsers developer tools open. Go to the network tab and you will see that the index.html is the first file loaded. Followed by other resources such as JavaScript, images and CSS

Comment: Thank you for your response, I saw the network tab and yes the first file in the network tab is index.html. Thanks for clearing my doubt

Comment: yeah ok but which entry point is executed first ?

Comment: index.html then main.ts

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.to/casperns/how-angular-trigger-indexhtml-and-start-working-1l46

- Angular started with main.ts.
- Then we bootstrap an angular
  application and we pass app.module.ts as an argument. In
  app.module.ts we tell angular: "There is the app component which you
  should know when you try to start yourself".
- And angular now analyze
  this app component, reading the set up we pass there and there is
  SELECTOR app-root.
- Now, angular is enable to handle app-root in the
  index.html and knows rules for the SELECTOR.
- SELECTOR should insert
  the app components and have some HTML code - a template attached to
  him - html component.
- This is how Angular application starts.

Comment: this answer should be validated